# How to update slider's maximum value based on user input in settings page when user presses Windows Phone back key?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a [Radial Slider Modern](http://sourceforge.net/projects/radialslider-wp/) on my MainPage.xaml. I set the maximum value for this using xaml 100. Code below

```
<my:RadialSliderModern x:Name="radialSliderModern"
                               Height="334"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Width="334"
                               SliderBrush="#F26464"
                               AllowKeyboardInput="False"
                               ShowSliderValue="True"
                               CurrentValue="0"
                               MaximumValue="100"
                               DataContext="{Binding}"
                               SliderValueChanged="sliderValueChanged"
                               Foreground="#F26464"
                               FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" />
```

I've created a settings page and an input field where the user can change the maximum. When this input field looses focus I use this method to store that value

```
    private void maxValueUserBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (maxValueUser.Text.Length != 0)
        {

            maxVal = (int)Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(maxValueUser.Text));
            maxValueUser.Text = maxVal.ToString();

            if (!settingsStorage.Contains("maxVal"))
            {
                settingsStorage.Add("maxVal", maxVal);
            }
            else
            {
                settingsStorage["maxVal"] = maxVal;
            }
            settingsStorage.Save();

        }

    }
```

I've figured out that by calling this piece of code in MainPage() constructor, I can update the maximum value of slider on startup but can't figure out what event to use if I want to update the maximum value when the user presses back button on settings page and navigates to the MainPage. Any Ideas ?

```
        if (settingsStorage.Contains("maxVal"))
        {
            radialSliderModern.MaximumValue = Convert.ToDouble(settingsStorage["maxVal"]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to use the Loaded event handler on the MainPage.xaml

```
Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded"
```

and in the code behind file

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    update_Slider();
}
```